# CiviRules and bulk email events

Tags: civirules

I'm interested in creating workflow based on bulk email opens and click throughs.  Is this possible with CiviRules?  If no, is support for these events planned?

Comment: Mike - how about you outline the workflow you are thinking about in case it rings some other bells for others.

Comment: may also be worth noting your CMS, since we built integration with Drupal Rules/Entities so stuff can be done through that channel on D7.

Comment: im on joomla 3.4.1.  

the workflow is probably add them to a group so we can send more tailored email in the iteration.  but we've talked about a number of other actions (eg send an email immediately),  change the acl on the member,  etc...

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no!

Yes, this would certainly be possible within the framework which CiviRules is build on.

No, currently this specific event has not been developed. Conceptually this doesn't seem to be too difficult event to create. You or your developer can try to do it yourself using the new [cookbook on CiviRules](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/281870344), or consider funding this work to be done by the first creators of the extension.

Comment: ok -- more reading for me.   will post an update if im going to attempt.  if not we'll consider other options.

Comment: I think it would be pretty straight forward, so it would maybe take only a couple of hours in the hands of the right developer. Good luck:-)

Comment: Mike - did you give this a go? If so which version of civi? Trying to find evidence of civirules working on 4.6

Comment: We've just been talking about exactly this sort of functionality: having CiviRules triggers for a tracked open and a clickthrough, with conditions enabling us to filter down to identified mailings and links. If anyone has done work on this that would be great.